# I am not able to run the Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am able to record the jmeter script successfully from Mozilla.

But I am not able to run the JMeter script.

In the console, I am getting messages like thread group started and finished but
in the listeners, I am not getting any results.

[image]

Can anybody help me whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) `22 /Bird/Login` and `37 /Bird/Login` under the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) so your test would look like:

[image: JMeter Test Plan Example]

---

Also be aware that you can quickly and easily configure JMeter for recording using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature, if you choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` from JMeter main menu and click "Create" - you will have a "good" Test Plan suitable for recording and replaying

[image: JMeter Templates Scripts]

Comment: Thanks for your Quick reply Dmitri...You save my day..how can i miss that simple step..Got It ..Now i am able to run it successfully..

Comment: And also thanks for the Jmeter Templates feature..Through that i am able to solve my another error also..Great Help..

Answer (score 0):

You have put View Results tree as child the wrong thread group.

Due to scoping rules in JMeter, it doesn’t receive any SampleResult from the Recorded Samples you are repalying.

So move it so that it becomes a child of Test Plan and you’ll get what you want